# Save PDF from a specific website in a specific directory

Tags: safari, pdf

I surf in the internet with Safari. When I download a file, it is automatically saved into the default directory "Downloads".

I usually download pdfs from http://arxiv.org and https://journals.aps.org and I would like to automatically save those pdfs in a different directory, say "Papers", **without** using "Save as" and then choosing the directory.

In other words, I want to modify the default download directory only for specific URLs such that only files downloaded from these URLs are saved into the second directory. All the rest of the files will be stored into "Download"

Is there a way to do so? Even a button in the Safari Toolbar is ok

Comment: Have you considered an automator script that finds and moves any pdf in the download folder triggered by activity in the download folder? You may find similar scripts exist that you can edit if you have a search.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want

Comment: I mean if you're willing to use Chrome, there's this extension: [Downloads Router](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-router/fgkboeogiiklpklnjgdiaghaiehcknjo). It only allows saving to the subfolders within the downloads folder but someone wrote instructions on how to get past that issue in the Reviews tab.

Comment: @SolarMike's suggestions achieves the outcome you describe.  Safari saves to Downloads and something else moves the pdf to wherever you want.  I would use Hazel rather than Automator - you have choices all of which would work.